# How to concatenate multiple rows inside a single row in SQL?

Tags: sql, db2

How do I concatenate multiple rows into a single row using SQL? My database is DB2

```
TableFoo
 -------
 Id      Name
 1       Apples
 1       Tomatoes
 1       Potatoes
 2       Banana
 2       Peach
```

I want something like

```
ID       FruitsAvailable
-------------------------
 1       Apples, Tomatoes, Potatoes
```

Comment: That depends on the DBMS you are using.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal I am using DB2 guys

Comment: The answer on the post is not what I am looking forward to.. I suppose there are many other ways

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Does GROUP_CONCAT work in DB2?

Comment: @AndriyM: You are right, it doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: Recurssion can be avoided with a function but maybe there is some other way without using a database function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this

```
  SELECT id ,FruitsAvailable 
  FROM
      (SELECT id , group_concat(Name) as FruitsAvailable 
       FROM  TableFoo
       WHERE id = 1) t
```

[**HERE DEMO SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b104/3)

EDIT:
in db2 you need to create function and then call it

```
 CREATE FUNCTION MySchema/MyUDF (
PARCol2 CHAR(5) )
RETURNS VARCHAR(1024)   
LANGUAGE SQL 
NOT DETERMINISTIC 
READS SQL DATA 
CALLED ON NULL INPUT 
DISALLOW PARALLEL 

 BEGIN 
  DECLARE ReturnVal VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL DEFAULT '';

  FOR CsrC1 AS C1 CURSOR 
      FOR SELECT MyCol1 
             FROM MyTable 
             WHERE MyCol2 = ParCol2 
      DO SET ReturnVal = ReturnVal Concat CsrC1.MyCol1; 
  END FOR; 

  RETURN LTRIM(ReturnVal); 
 END  ;
```

and then call it here

```
     Select  id, MyUDF(Name) as FruitsAvailable
     From TableFoo 
     where id = 1
```

Comment: -1: GROUP_CONCAT is MySql, it doesn't exist in DB2

Comment: Can't get it to work. I think group_concat is not supported on DB2

Comment: Thanks! Is using a cursor necessary?

Comment: I am having a problem with this, The function keeps returning "++++++++++" no matter what I give it and I tried changing around quite a lot of stuff but it keeps doing that. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: @StevenRogers yeah...ditch DB2.  That's what my company is doing and it's not a minute too soon.

Comment: @cbmeeks This is a client's database. They already denied switching and are sticking to it like glue. I was able to find a workaround for my last comment a few days after it was posted, wish I remembered what it was so I could share it with the world.

Answer (score -3):

Use this query:

```
SELECT Id, GROUP_CONCAT(Name SEPARATOR ', ') FROM TableFoo GROUP BY Id;
```

Comment: -1: GROUP_CONCAT is MySql, it doesn't exist in DB2