# How to Merge 2 Rows into one by comma separate?

Tags: sql, database, db2

I need to merge this individual rows to one column, I now how to merge column by comma separated,

```
+---------------+-------+-------+
|CID            |Flag   |Value  |
+---------------+-------+-------+
|1              |F      |10     |
|1              |N      |20     |
|2              |F      |12     |
|2              |N      |23     |
|2              |F      |14     |
|3              |N      |21     |
|3              |N      |22     |
+---------------+-------+-------+
```

Desired Result can be anything,

```
+-----------+----------------------------+    +--------------------------+
|Part Number| Value                      |    | Value                    |   
+-----------+----------------------------+    +--------------------------+
| 1         | 1|F|10 ; 1|N|20            | Or | 1|F|10 ; 1|N|20          |
| 2         | 2|F|12 ; 2|N|23 ; 2|F|14   |    | 2|F|12 ; 2|N|23 ; 2|F|14 |
| 3         | 3|N|21 ; 3|N|22            |    | 3|N|21 ; 3|N|22          |
+-----------+----------------------------+    +--------------------------+
```

**Note:**

> Any hint in right direction with small example is more than enough

**EDIT :**
I have massive data in tables like thousands of records where parent's and child relationship is present. I have to dump this into text files by comma separated values In single line as record. Think as primary record has relationship with so many other table then all this record has to be printed as a big line.

And I am trying to achieve by creating query so load can be distributed on database and only thing i have to worry about in business is just dumping logic into text files or whatever form we need in future.

Comment: could you explain the reason behind trying to get this representation?

Comment: @vkp look for explanation

Comment: It appears that in DB2 you have create a custom function.  Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14851025/how-to-concatenate-multiple-rows-inside-a-single-row-in-sql) for an example to get you started.

Comment: possible duplicate of [DB2 comma separated output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188542/db2-comma-separated-output)

Comment: @jradich1234 merging single column can be achieved but merging entire row that's what i want

Comment: Whats is the Database: Sql Server?

Comment: What DB2 version and platform?

Comment: @JBaba - merging multiple columns from a single row is a subproblem of merging the rows, so the techniques still work regardless.  Note that there's no way to guarantee the ordering of children at all.  Why are you supposed to output them as a single row?  If you're doing import/export of data, you're going to find that working with non-concatenated data will make your life a lot easier; a number of systems will probably squawk at you if you give it varying-length records.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [LISTAGG](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0058709.html) and your query will look like this:

```
select a.cid, a.cid || listagg(a.flag || '|' || a.value, ',') 
from foo.dat a
group by a.cid
```

You can use different separators and of course play with how the result will be formatted.

Comment: DB2 ZOS doesn't have `LISTAGG` but it can be reproduced using `XMLAGG`